# Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data: ymax, ymin, x, y

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I have been trying to work around this error for a bit, but can't seem to resolve it.

I have a combined barplot as seen in the picture and I want to compute the error bars for each time frame (6, 8, 12 weeks and terminal). I used the summarySE function to find the values for each time frame, and this is the code I am using to create the graph along with the errorbars:

```
limits <- aes (ymax= summarySE_data$mean + summarySE_data$se, ymin = summarySE_data$mean - summarySE_data$se)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = df$time_frame,  y = df$Engraftment_Efficiency , group = time_frame)) + scale_fill_discrete(breaks = c("six weeks", "eight weeks", "twelve weeks", "terminal point"))

p + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9)) + geom_errorbar(limits, position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.25, group = "Sample." )+ labs(x = NULL , y= "Engraftment Efficiency %") + ggtitle("PBL Engraftment Efficiency")
```

I have seen other posts regarding a similar error, however they haven't worked for me. Any input on how to resolve this error is appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

Here is my main df:

```
    time_frame Engraftment_Efficiency
1       six weeks                     49.8
2       six weeks                     47.3
3       six weeks                     56.1
4       six weeks                     36.7
5       six weeks                     54.8
6       six weeks                     48.0
7     eight weeks                     64.7
8     eight weeks                     52.0
9     eight weeks                     68.1
10    eight weeks                     47.2
11    eight weeks                     59.1
12    eight weeks                     65.5
13   twelve weeks                     72.6
14   twelve weeks                     55.0
15   twelve weeks                     77.3
16   twelve weeks                     61.4
17   twelve weeks                     73.4
18   twelve weeks                     72.6
19 terminal point                     69.8
20 terminal point                     43.2
```

and here is the summarySE_data:

```
       time_frame  N     mean        sd       se        ci
1      six weeks  6       48.78333  6.922259 2.826000  7.264465
2    eight weeks  6       59.43333  8.302690 3.389559  8.713139
3   twelve weeks  6       68.71667  8.572611 3.499754  8.996404
4 terminal point 11       71.48182 20.684817 6.236707 13.896249
```

Comment: Never use `data$` inside `aes`. Just use the bare column name. The data frame should be passed to the layer of the plot, or inherited from the original `ggplot()` call. This does mean you won't be able to pre-define `limits` like you are.

Comment: The way you have things set up, the height of the bar is the maximum for each group. Is that what you want? It looks strange to me with the error bars mostly below the tops of the barplot bars.

Comment: No, I am actually not sure why it's coming up like that. I am looking for the standard dev error bars that extend above the max height of the bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `data$` inside `aes`. The data comes from the `data =` argument, inside `aes()` you should just have column names.

Here's my best guess at what will work. Can't test without seeing your data, and your `group = "Sample."` is very strange because it is not in `aes()`, it is a string, can't tell if it's a column name, so I just deleted it.

```
p <-
ggplot(
    df,
    aes(x = time_frame,
        y = Engraftment_Efficiency ,
        group = time_frame)
  ) +
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks = c("six weeks", "eight weeks", "twelve weeks", "terminal point")) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  geom_errorbar(
    data = summarySE_data,
    aes(ymax = mean + se,
        ymin = mean - se),
    position = position_dodge(0.9),
    width = 0.25
  ) +
  labs(x = NULL , y = "Engraftment Efficiency %", title = "PBL Engraftment Efficiency")
```

---

This is my best guess for what you want:

```
ggplot(
    summarySE_data,
    aes(x = time_frame,
        y = mean,
        group = time_frame)
  ) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  geom_errorbar(
    data = summarySE_data,
    aes(ymax = mean + se,
        ymin = mean - se),
    position = position_dodge(0.9),
    width = 0.25
  ) +
  labs(x = NULL , y = "Engraftment Efficiency %", title = "PBL Engraftment Efficiency")
```

Here we only use the summary data frame - the height of the bars is the mean, and the error bars show +/- the standard error. It doesn't seem like the plot needs the raw data frame at all.

If you do use the raw data in another layer, you may have to set `inherit.aes = FALSE` in the `geom_errobar` layer (and specify its `x` aesthetic), otherwise it will look for the `y` column in the data, not find it, and complain.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Sorry forgot to change the "Sample.", that refers to the time frame. In my summarySE_data I also have the time frame column and I wanted to group the error bars by the time frame (not sure if that's the way to do it though). I tried your code and I am getting the following errors: "Error in +scale_fill_discrete... invalid argument to unary operator" and "Error in + labs.... invalid argument to unary operator"

Comment: Those errors sound like syntax errors - as if you changed where the linebreaks are and ended up with `+ labs(...)` on a line by itself. I can't run any of the code since I don't have your data. If you edit some sample data into your question I can take a look (use `dput()` so it is copy/pasteable!). But without sample data I can't do anything more.

Comment: Just posted the input. Thank you!

Comment: See edits. I think you just need to be plotting the summary data frame.

Comment: Thanks so much! That all worked with the summary data frame.